# Z-score distributions are not normal, explain how this still works, and how relevant this is when calculating them on a per-protein basis

Tags: normal-distribution, z-score

I did some data analysis using Z-score. For example, I have 10 proteins(N length) in my dataset. I did some prediction of each protein and that gave me residue wise score. Then we have calculated Z-score for each residue position in protein and plot Z-score distribution for 10 proteins. My observation was that Z-score distribution was skewed. Based on Z-score I did classification if Z<0 then those residue will be class1 and if Z>0 then those residue class 2. but someone asked me question 'Z-score distributions are not normal, explain how this still works, and how relevant this is when calculating them on a per-protein basis'
I gave this answer Z-score distribution is mirror of original distribution so thats why it skewed but it works.how it works that i need statistical explanation.
I am not statistical expert so can anyone help me to get right mathematical explanation of my question.
Thanks

Comment: If you used the formula $z = \frac{x - \text{mean}}{\text{SD}}$ then any values below the mean will have a negative z-score and any above the mean will have a positive z-score. As it is currently written, the question is quite unclear. When you say "explain how this still works", what does "this" mean?

Comment: how this classification still works based on +ve and -ve Z-score criteria where we have observed Z-score distribution was skewed for whole dataset? is not giving some bias result ? Although I am note sure I have used right statistical term

Comment: What is the result you are attempting to achieve? What would it mean for this result to be biased? You are correct that if the original distribution is skewed then the distribution of z-scores will be skewed too, but how does this relate to the classification problem?

Answer (score 1):

You standardized the data in your data set and ensured it would have a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1. However, this merely shifts and shrinks/stretches your data.  The shape of your data is not going to change.  As such, standardizing won't make the data Normal and it won't remove a skew. The standardized data will be Normal only if the original data is Normally shaped and the standardized data will not be skewed only if the original data is not skewed.

Comment: I think, though it is not entirely clear, that the OP already knows this - when they saw the z-score distribution "mirrors" the original distribution, and therefore it is skewed, this is what they're getting at. But your answer doesn't address the classification issue.

Comment: Mu understanding was that OP was wondering how the distribution of $Z$-scores still skewed. OP mentioned that it mirrored the original distribution, but not *why*. I could have certainly misinterpreted the question, however!

Comment: Helpful, but the word "necessarily" should be omitted. As you say, standardization doesn't change distribution shape, so it can't even happen by accident that standardizing a distribution gets it closer to normal.

Comment: I'll edit it, Nick! I think the problem arises when I say that it would necessarily *make* the data Normal. I want to express that the standardized data need not be Normal.

Comment: Indeed, but your sentence is now correct and clearer.

Comment: Apologies if my original comment seemed unduly critical - I'm not completely sure what the original poster was asking (and hope that they clarify at some point!) but the *classification* issue, and what this meant on a "per protein basis", appeared to be important to them. I agree with Nick Cox that this answer is at least correct and clear; whether it addresses what the OP wants is hard to know until there's some clarification.

Comment: Thanks. at least from your comments it is clear I can use Z-score although it skewed .